# Wheel alignment based on different vehicle model

Tags: toyota, wheels, alignment

I have a Toyota Solara 2006, and the auto repair has done wheel alignment on my vehicle based on the specifications of Toyota Solara 1999-2003 models. Is this a problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Yes, it could be. Obviously something is different or the year range would include yours. How do you know it is wrong? Did they admit to doing it wrong? Have them do it correctly.

Comment: This is why you should always request a print of the alignment measurements.  Even if you don't know or care about the numbers it forces the tech to actually key in the correct vehicle to the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Auto Zone](http://www.autozone.com/repairguides/Toyota-Avalon-Camry-Camry-Solara-2001-06/Wheel-Alignment/Wheel-Alignment-Specifications/_/P-0996b43f803789a0) these are the alignment specs for 2003 and 2006 Toyotas:
[image: 2003][image: 2006]
As you can see, front caster and camber are quite different; toe-in is the same. I would either find a different mechanic or ask yours why they're using the wrong specs for your car. Personally, I'd opt for the former, as they've obviously shown a proclivity towards dishonesty or laziness, which isn't going to be fixed by your calling them on it. In my experience, when cheaters get caught cheating, they just find other ways to cheat (just my $0.02).

Answer (score 0):

Without researching the Solara, I can't say conclusively that it's a problem. However.. Did you ask them why they did that? The second generation Solara is based on a completely different platform to the first generation.

You could call a Toyota dealer and ask them to check it. An alignment check wouldn't cost much compared to new tires if it's badly out of spec. If the repair is going through your insurance company, they might be interested to know if a repairer is cutting corners.